# Need help in replacing Numeric value in list of strings using regular expression Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would need help in replacing the numeric value from the Python list of strings. I could map some part of the strings, however there were concern over two replacement on the same string. I am looking for a exact match replacement and as I was very new to the regular expression couldn't match properly. Any help would be really appreciated.

Below is the example I tried.

```
tomap = ['14','83','9']

textlist = ['World11118','helloWD11','Stop12']

oldvalue = ['1111','11','12']

dict_set = dict(zip(oldvalue, tomap))

p = r'\b(?<=\D)' + '|'.join(oldvalue) + r'(?=\z)\b'

[re.sub(p, lambda x: dict_set[x.group()],i) for i in  textlist]
```

Expected Output: Out[165]:

```
['World11118', 'helloWD83', 'Stop9']
```

Current Output: Out[165]:

```
['World83838', 'helloWD83', 'Stop12']
```

Comment: why is the first value in expected output same as the first value in the textlist? was there no replacement done to it? do you need the output to be `['World148', 'helloWD83', 'Stop9']`???

Comment: Thank you Onyambu for the quick response...If the values from oldvalue doesn't match exactly, we shouldn't the replace the values. So I was looking for an exact value matching and replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

This tests that the previous character is a non-digit. and use `$` to show the end of the string. Also you can use `\\b` to indicate the boundary instead of `$` depending on how your strings are, and what best suits you.

```
[re.sub('(?<=\\D)'+ k + '$', i, j) for i, j, k in zip(tomap, textlist, oldvalue)]
Out[256]: ['World11118', 'helloWD83', 'Stop9']
```

Comment: Thank you so much Onyambu...This is very helpful. This saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: If this solves the problem, you can accept the solution by clicking on the check mark against the solution

Comment: Thank you Onyambu

Comment: Hi Onyambu,Just out of curiosity..How this would happen on the syntax mentioned above..? [re.sub( '(?<=\\D)' + '|'.join(dict_set.keys()) + '(?=\\b)', lambda x: dict_set[x.group()],i) for i in  textlist] ? am I missing something..?

Comment: for you to be able to use your way, then you need to capture all the options as one group:: ie `(?<=\\D)(1111|11|12)(?=\\b)` is what you are looking for. where `1111|11|12` are all within the parenthesis such that each of them is affected by the lookbehind and the lookahead. Otherwise with no parenthesis, the lookbehind only affects the 1111 while the look ahead affects the 12. so you should rather do `p = r'(?<=\D)(' + '|'.join(oldvalue) + r')(?=\\b)'`

Comment: Thank you Onyambu. Really appreciate the prompt reply. Looks like I need to do some more modification to get similar to the other approach.